Positivity of caloric measure density on a cylinder
Let $u$ be a solution to the heat equation $u_t = \Delta u$ in the unit cylinder $B_1\times(-1,0) \subset \mathbb R^{n+1}$.
Then, it is well known (see for instance Chapter 2 in "Watson - Introduction to heat potential theory") that one can write
$$u(0,0) = \int_{B_1\times\{0\}}u(x,-1)\mathrm{d}\omega_i(x) + \int_0^1\int_{\partial B_1}u(x,t)\mathrm{d}\omega_l(x,t),$$
and that $\omega_i$ and $\omega_l$ are nonnegative measures, absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue $n$-dimensional measure.
I need a reference for the fact that the densities are uniformly positive away from $\partial B_1 \times \{-1,0\}$.
Edit: typo.

Hi Clara, I am a bit confused: the measures should depend on the point $(x,t)$ where you are evaluating the solution, correct? Your desired estimate should hold true only  if $(x,t)$ is uniformly away from the parabolic boundary. In that case it should boils down to some Haranck type inequality. Check the last section of Caffarelli-Salsa book "A geometric approach to free boundary problems"

Hi Guido, I actually need it only at (0,0), there was a typo. Thanks for the reference, the book points out to "Estimates of Caloric Measure and the Initial-Dirichlet Problem for the Heat Equation in Lipschitz Cylinders" by Fabes and Salsa (Transactions of the AMS 1983).
However, that result only applies to the lateral boundary.
I think I know how to do it for the initial condition using barriers and the heat kernel, but it's extremely computation heavy and probably overkill.

Do you have a response to the answer below?

$\newcommand\om\omega$It is convenient to restate the problem probabilistically. In particular, we will then have the heat equation written as
$$u_t+\tfrac12\,\Delta u=0$$
in $B_1\times(0,1]$, with the time reversal and space rescaling. Here $B_1$ is the unit ball in $\Bbb R^d$. (?)
Then, according to Theorems 2.1 and 3.2 in Doob's paper A PROBABILITY APPROACH TO THE HEAT EQUATION, we have
$$\om_\ell(dx\times dt)=P(\tau\in[t,t+dt],W_\tau\in dx),\quad
\om_i(dx)=P(\tau=1,W_1\in dx),$$
where $W_\cdot$ is a standard Brownian motion in $\Bbb R^n$ and
$$\tau:=\inf\{t\ge0\colon(W_t,t)\notin B_1\times(0,1]\}.$$
The desired conclusion is then the following:

the measure $\om_\ell$ has a density that is bounded away from $0$ on $\partial B_1\times(h,1]$ for each $h\in(0,1)$;
the measure $\om_i$ has a density that is bounded away from $0$ on $B_1$.

The proof of this conclusion is somewhat tedious but straightforward, done by considering the probabilities of the Brownian motion trajectory staying within a neighborhood of a segment of a straight line in $\Bbb R^{n+1}$ -- using e.g. the Cameron-Martin formula for the Radon--Nikodym density of the distribution of a shifted Brownian motion wrt to that of the non-shifted one.
